# single paging page size in operating system

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

In our exam the question was asked, and I couldn't answer it. However, I wonder its answer.

> If there exist `2^N` bit virtual addressing, `2^M` bit physical
>   addressing and `2^L` kb page size. In single paging, what is the page
>   size?

Comment: Is "single paging" a technical term with a specific meaning in the book / course you're using?  I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I'd assume that's supposed to be "single level paging" (e.g. page directory only, rather than 2 or more levels).

Comment: @Brendan: that's possible, but doesn't make the question answerable (beyond just saying `2^L kB`).  Maybe the question is also supposed to be asking about the page *table* size, because the page size is one of the free parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is unanswerable unless you make random/unfounded assumptions.

For a silly example, you could assume that there are only 2 physical pages and only one virtual page (`M == N-1`), and that the page table is the same size as a page (and only has one page table entry) and therefore a page table entry consumes `2^L` bits where one of these bits are used to select the physical page and all of the other bits are used for other purposes (access permissions, tracking accessed/dirty, spare bits for the OS to use however it likes, ...).